# ObjectDisposedException was unhandled when closing form using System.Net.Mail namespace

Tags: vb.net, smtp

This is the error I'm getting when `Me.Close()` is called:

[image]

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            mail.From = New MailAddress("your email@domain.com")
            mail.[To].Add("to@domain.com")
            mail.Subject = "Trial"
            mail.Body = "Trial"


            Dim path As String = "C:\Users\CrystalUser\Desktop\trial"
            Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(path)
            Dim filesInDirectory As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles()
            Dim attach As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
            For Each file In filesInDirectory
                attach = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file.FullName)
                mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
            Next


            SmtpServer.Port = 587
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True

            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("Sent Successfuly", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send")

        Catch alvin As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(alvin.Message)
        End Try
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

I want the program to close automatically after sending the `MailMessage`.

I have used `Me.Hide()` and `Me.Close()` but neither worked.

Comment: Please edit the details of the error into the question, along with the line it happens on (if possible)

Comment: Does the error happen on when you do me.close or  SmtpServer.Send(mail)? There shouldnt be any object that need closed. If it is happening on me.close you may want to move the email into a separate method.

Comment: Use `Finally  Me.Close()`...like `Try
        'Do something
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Handle exception
    Finally
        Me.Close()
    End Try`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your error is little unclear and this answer may not fix your problem it would be wise to implement [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) on the [MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k0ddab0(v=vs.110).aspx), [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w4as51(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56wesadc(v=vs.110).aspx) classes:

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished with them. This makes them available for other code to use.

I would also look at reducing some unnecessary code when using `.GetFiles()`.

Code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        Using mail As New MailMessage("your email@domain.com", "to@domain.com", "Trial", "Trial"),
              smtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

            Dim filesInDirectory As FileInfo() = New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\CrystalUser\Desktop\trial").GetFiles()
            For Each file In filesInDirectory
                Using attach As New Attachment(file.FullName)
                    mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
                End Using
            Next

            smtpServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = True

            smtpServer.Send(mail)

            MessageBox.Show("Mail sent")
        End Using
    Catch alvin As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(alvin.Message)
    End Try

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

The point of implementing `Using` is so that the objects are disposed of properly once finished with. The objects will also be disposed of before entering the `Catch` statement, should any errors occur.

Give this a go and let me know how you get on.